# Помогите разобраться с потоком в Android

Tags: java, android, многопоточность

Есть код, который в потоке получает данные от контролера:

```
Handler mHandler = new Handler();
private void tvAppend(TextView tv, CharSequence text) {
    final TextView ftv = tv;
    final CharSequence ftext = text;
    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ftv.append(ftext);
        }
    });
}
```

Как мне в этот же поток запихнуть команду которая должна работать вечно в потоке с задержкой в 100 миллисекунд

```
bytesToSend = addCRC(new byte[]{1, 0x3, 0, 0 ,0, 0});
mPhysicaloid.write(bytesToSend, bytesToSend.length);
```

Весь код можно увидеть https://github.com/ksksue/PhysicaloidLibrary/blob/master/SampleProjects/tutorial5/src/com/physicaloid/tutorial5/Tutorial5Activity.java

---

**UPD:** Если я правильно понял ответ @saidolim-djuraev
то мой код сейчас должен быть таким:

```
Handler mHandler = new Handler();
private void tvAppend(TextView tv, CharSequence text) {
    final TextView ftv = tv;
    final CharSequence ftext = text;
    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ftv.append(ftext);

            while (true) {
                bytesToSend = addCRC(new byte[]{1, 0x3, 0, 0, 0, 0});
                mPhysicaloid.write(bytesToSend, bytesToSend.length);

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Но как тогда этот поток запустить в одном методе, а остановить поток при выполнении другого метода ?

Comment: `Но как тогда этот поток запустить в одном методе, а остановить поток при выполнении другого метода ?` это уже другой вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть пару моментов:

1. Handler используют для того, что бы выполнить код в UI-потоке, и всякие другие дела в нем делать не стоит.
2. Для того, что бы делать какую-то операцию с фиксированной задержкой или фиксированной частотой, стоит использовать пакет *java.util.concurrent*.

   ```
   ScheduledExecutorService mExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

   private void tvAppend(TextView tv, CharSequence text) {
       final TextView ftv = tv; 
       final CharSequence ftext = text;

       ftv.append(ftext);

       mExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(getRunnable(addCRC(new byte[]{1, 0x3, 0, 0 ,0, 0})), 0, 100 , TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
   }


   public Runnable getRunnable(final byte[] data){
       return new Runnable(){
           @Override public void run(){
               mPhysicaloid.write(data, data.length);
           }
       };
   }
   ```

Comment: Если я верно понял, то вы предлагаете использовать ваш метод вместо моего Handler ?

Comment: Да. Если Handler-ом выполнять медленный код, а особенно спать в нем, то UI приложения просто зависнет и не будет отвечать.  Плюс, кажется подобным способом (тот же mExecutor, только другой метод) я предложил решение на другой ваш вопрос, так что в коде будет некая целостность и порядок.

Comment: Рекомендую ознакомиться: http://habrahabr.ru/post/116363/

Comment: Посмотрите: [ссылка 1](http://hsto.org/files/fab/502/f0e/fab502f0e55c4de5a174fedab5e85931.jpg) и [ссылка 2](https://hsto.org/files/2f0/8cc/065/2f08cc0655884efb956ee19f782d52d3.jpg)

Как это можно исправить ?

Comment: Сори, опечатка. new Runnable() { ... }

Comment: Эта штука называется Анонимный класс. Позволяет сразу создать инстанс интерфейса, тут же написав реализацию метода.

Comment: и как я понимаю return new Runnable(){ закрывается с точкой запятой а не только фигурной дужкой :-)

Comment: Только вот беда, при использовании данного метода, а точнее при отправке команд рушиться вся программа и ошибки показывает тогда как в моем классе так и в других от драйвера, вы наверное не смотрели как мой код работает: [ссылка](https://github.com/ksksue/PhysicaloidLibrary/blob/master/SampleProjects/tutorial5/src/com/physicaloid/tutorial5/Tutorial5Activity.java) это тот код, который я переделываю под свою задачу

Comment: Хм, Physicaloidу контекст активити нужен... Но тогда ну тогда то, что всередине [можно тоже обвернуть в Runnable](https://gist.github.com/DarkMentat/6fd1e29c78872961ba4a). Нехилая вложенность получиться, но понять можно: создаем Runnable, который запускается в потоке mExecutor'a и он создает там, в другом потоке, другой Runnable, который уже запускается в UI-шном потоке.

Comment: В принципе, раз нужен контекст, можно попробывать поиграться `mHandler.postDelayed(getRunnable(/*...*/), 100);` Он умеет запускать Runnable в UI-потоке с задержкой, но не умеет делать что-то типа scheduleAtFixedRate. Но можно сказать, что бы каждый Runnable запускал таким же образом другой, с такой же задержкой, проверяя какой-то флаг для того, что б можно было это дело остановить. Но спать в mHandler не стоит, так это точно.

Comment: Ой, вы меня полностью запутали, а можете показать как все это должно выглядеть, а то меня сами слова "Но тогда ну тогда то" уже путают. mPhysicaloid.write(data, data.length); используется для отправки пакетов, мне его нужно запускать когда устройство подключено, то есть в методе openDevice() и нужно чтобы цикл останавливался если устройство отключилось, метод closeDevice(), но и когда отправляется другая команда (не цикл) то нужно делать паузу и ждать пока не получу ответа (примерно 20 мс) и продолжать цикл

Comment: [как-то так](https://gist.github.com/DarkMentat/6fd1e29c78872961ba4a).

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное, завтра уже буду пробовать данный метод, о результате отпишусь !

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте

```
@Override
public void run() {
    ftv.append(ftext);

    while(true){
        bytesToSend = addCRC(new byte[]{1, 0x3, 0, 0 ,0, 0});
        mPhysicaloid.write(bytesToSend, bytesToSend.length);

        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }

    }
}
```

**UPD:**

для

> Но как тогда этот поток запустить в одном методе, а остановить поток при выполнении другого метода ?

вам нужно создать отделный `class` для `runnable` и создать `boolean` переменную для управления цикла `while`. как:

```
private static boolean canWork=true;
...
while(canWork) {...}
```

для остановки делаете

```
<имя класса>.canWork = false;
```

Comment: чуть позже попробую данный метод, но у меня зразу возник вопрос, можно ли останавливать поток, если можно то как ?
И еще один глупый вопрос, можно ли при отправке другой команды в данном цикле делать паузу и ждать ответа и как только ответ пришел продолжать дальше выполнение цикла.


Ответы получает append (Правда если я правильно все понимаю).

(Строго не судите, с потоками не работал да и новенький я в этом)